# Expose Container in virtual network to public Azure

Tags: linux, azure, azure-networking, virtual-network, azure-container-service

I have an Azure cosmos DB instance configured to allow access from a private virtual network: icy-horizon. I also have an API deployed using Azure Container Instances with port 80 exposed attached to icy-horizon network as it needs to communicate with the DB.

How can I expose the API to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general container groups deployed to a virtual network don't currently support exposing containers directly to the internet with a public IP address or a fully qualified domain name.

You would have to deploy an application gateway in addition to expose the container to the internet. See this [Expose a static IP address for a container group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway) for more information.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for clearing that up! I was trying to set it up like a VM, using a notwork instance, subnet, nsg, ip and instead of the VM, the container that didn't work cuz container instances deployment couldn't delegate the subnet to the new resource. Thanks!

Comment: @Sid: I had a similar problem, because I was deploying the container and the application gateway in the same subnet. A subnet can only be delegated once. The solution is to use two subnets inside the same vnet.